# Prevent icons from flashing during ArcGIS FeatureService layer refresh

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, feature-service

Here is my current situation:

- Web Mapping app built with ESRI WebAppBuilder 2.10
- FeatureService of geometry type Point with Feature Access and Web Mapping capabilities enabled generates features from table on PostGIS database. Uses the column PK as the ObjectID. Contains ~ 400 features on average that may have any of their properties changing except for ID.
- Web Map contains FeatureService and draws features markers on map.
- During layer refresh on 5 second interval, all the features are redrawn, the icons blink off and then back on, giving the app a very janky feel.

Is it possible to prevent the features from removed and then re-drawn to the map during layer refresh? I couldn't find anything specific to this in ESRI documentation, and the map layer drawing logic is contained by default within ESRI's CDN, and is difficult to access through the file available in the WebAppBuilder application.

I've tried disabling custom symbology (I've assigned custom icons within the layer definition) and using different unique values for the ObjectID, but still no dice. It seems like maintaining a live FeatureService that is updated frequently is a fairly basic use case, but I can't find any kind of support for this on the ESRI forums.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For layer refresh, the previous layer is being removed and replaced with a new updated layer. When that occurs, the icons appear to flash as the old layer icons are dropped and the new layer icons are placed. The only method to stop the flashing is to not have the layer updated thereby never removing the old layer + its icons.

Comment: so there's no way to display live data without flashing icons? :-(

Comment: Since the flash is the result of the old layer being removed and the new layer added, no. At least none that I have been able to discover or have been told by Esri.